# In Sheet, Send email to a specific recipient when a cell is filled

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a sheet for project management to collaborate easily among many interlocutor (*I know there are free tools outhere working with a public organization is hellish to insert new procedures into the project*).

Here is the sample file created : [Google Sheet for Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUbw0WNju55h5pk3l8QqVCYa_jSCzrIzMjf0N4v-z8c/edit?usp=sharing)

The ideais everytime a new question is input, the author can select the menu **"Question"** > **"Send Question"**.
And it should sent automatic email to the **Recipient** email address (column C)... under the condition that **the Question cell is filled** (condition checked in "I2").

But currently, the script does not work as expected.

*Note*: I am currently learning JS.

**Here is the code :**

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Question')
      .addItem('Send Question', 'sendQuestion')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Send Answer', 'sendAnswer')
      .addToUi();
}


function sendQuestion() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Questions");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A22:L2");
  var emailvalid = range.getCell(1,7).getValue();
  var question = range.getCell(1,5).getValue();
  var answer = range.getCell(1,6).getValue();
  var qvalid = range.getCell(1,8).getValue();
  var ansvalid = range.getCell(1,10).getValue();

  if(qvalid == "Nope"){
      Browser.msgBox("Please, write a question !"); 
    }
  else {
    return false};
  
    if(emailvalid == "Nope"){
      Browser.msgBox("Please, input a valid email address !"); 
    }
  else {
    return false};
  
  var from = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();
  var recipient = range.getCell(1,2).getValue();
  var emailTo = range.getCell(1,3).getValue();
  var subject = "Project Management | Your received a new question" + question;
  var link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUbw0WNju55h5pk3l8QqVCYa_jSCzrIzMjf0N4v-z8c/edit?usp=sharing"
  var options = {}
        options.htmlBody = "Hi" + recipient +"," + "<br />"+ "<br />" + "You received a new question from " + from + "<br />" + "<br />" + "You can answer directly into the table here: "<"br />"+"<br />" + link + "<br />" + "<br />"+ "Thank you";
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, " ", options);

}

function emailSent(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sent = sendQuestion("Send Email ?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    
  if(sent == ui.Button.YES) {
    ui.alert("Your Message has been sent.");
  } else {
    ui.alert("Email canceled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're main error there is this `else return false` statement you have, which is basically terminating the function if your validation passes, where it should be the other way around, exiting the function if the validation fails, after you popup informing the problem.

```
if(qValid == 'Nope') {
  Browser.msgBox('etc...');
  return; //return here, not in the else clause
}
//same for email valid
```

There are quite a few other "improvements" I'd do on such function. But I guess it's beyond the point here, you're learning as you go and the most important is that it works now.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.